# how to check database already exists in sql server? and how stop the query if database already exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
IF EXISTS(select name from sys.databases where name = 'AdventureWorks')
   use AdventureWorks
```

I want to use `AdventureWorks` if it already exists, but if it doesn't exists, I want to create the `AdventureWorks` database.

Help me please.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Not sure: CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks WHERE NOT EXISTS(select name from sys.databases where name = 'AdventureWorks')

Answer (score 1):

```
if db_id('Test1') is not null
    set noexec on;

create database Test1;

set noexec off;
```

It seems, though, that you cannot switch the database context with USE in the same batch that creates it - MSSQL fires an error. So split it into 2 queries.